# How to convert a supplier to Stream?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have some supplier (possibly infinite):

```
class Supplier  {
  def get(): Int = ??? // returns some numbers
}
```

How can I convert it to `Stream`?

This is my solution:

```
 val supplier = new Supplier
 val stream = Stream.iterate(supplier.get)(_ => supplier.get)
```

I don't like this solution because I have to call `supplier.get` two times. Is there a more concise way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `continually`:

```
val supplier = new Supplier
val stream = Stream.continually(supplier.get)
```

It takes a by-name parameter, so `get` will be called every time a new element of the stream is required.